# Tomcat native library update

Tags: tomcat

I can't get rid of

```
An incompatible version 1.1.29 of the APR based Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version 1.1.30
```

in Intellij Idea. I think I just need to update that.

```
sudo apt-get upgrade libtcnative-1
```

didn't fix the problem. it says

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done Calculating upgrade... Done libtcnative-1 is
>   already the newest version. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove
>   and 0 not upgraded.

Error from Idea log:

```
/home/ivan/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/bin/catalina.sh run
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:60749', transport: 'socket'
[2014-09-23 02:11:57,027] Artifact perc-web:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Sep 23, 2014 2:11:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
SEVERE: An incompatible version 1.1.29 of the APR based Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version 1.1.30
APR Statistical data ....
Poll Statistics .........
Polls created           : 0
Polls destroyed         : 0
Polls cleared           : 0
Network Statistics ......
Sockets created         : 0
Sockets accepted        : 0
Sockets closed          : 0
Sockets cleared         : 0
Total send calls        : 0
Minimum send length     : 10000000
Maximum send length     : 0
Average send length     : -nan
Total recv calls        : 0
Minimum recv length     : 10000000
Maximum recv length     : 0
Average recv length     : -nan
Receive timeouts        : 0
Receive errors          : 0
Receive resets          : 0
Last receive error      : 0
Total sendfile calls    : 0
Minimum sendfile length : 10000000
Maximum sendfile length : 0
SSL Network Statistics ..
Sockets created         : 0
Sockets accepted        : 0
Sockets closed          : 0
Sockets cleared         : 0
APR Terminated
Sep 23, 2014 2:11:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
SEVERE: An incompatible version 1.1.29 of the APR based Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version 1.1.30
APR Statistical data ....
Poll Statistics .........
Polls created           : 0
Polls destroyed         : 0
Polls cleared           : 0
Network Statistics ......
Sockets created         : 0
Sockets accepted        : 0
Sockets closed          : 0
Sockets cleared         : 0
Total send calls        : 0
Minimum send length     : 10000000
Maximum send length     : 0
Average send length     : -nan
Total recv calls        : 0
Minimum recv length     : 10000000
Maximum recv length     : 0
Average recv length     : -nan
Receive timeouts        : 0
Receive errors          : 0
Receive resets          : 0
Last receive error      : 0
Total sendfile calls    : 0
Minimum sendfile length : 10000000
Maximum sendfile length : 0
SSL Network Statistics ..
Sockets created         : 0
Sockets accepted        : 0
Sockets closed          : 0
Sockets cleared         : 0
APR Terminated
Sep 23, 2014 2:11:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
SEVERE: An incompatible version 1.1.29 of the APR based Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version 1.1.30
APR Statistical data ....
Poll Statistics .........
Polls created           : 0
Polls destroyed         : 0
Polls cleared           : 0
Network Statistics ......
Sockets created         : 0
Sockets accepted        : 0
Sockets closed          : 0
Sockets cleared         : 0
Total send calls        : 0
Minimum send length     : 10000000
Maximum send length     : 0
Average send length     : -nan
Total recv calls        : 0
Minimum recv length     : 10000000
Maximum recv length     : 0
Average recv length     : -nan
Receive timeouts        : 0
Receive errors          : 0
Receive resets          : 0
Last receive error      : 0
Total sendfile calls    : 0
Minimum sendfile length : 10000000
Maximum sendfile length : 0
SSL Network Statistics ..
Sockets created         : 0
Sockets accepted        : 0
Sockets closed          : 0
Sockets cleared         : 0
APR Terminated
Sep 23, 2014 2:11:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
SEVERE: An incompatible version 1.1.29 of the APR based Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version 1.1.30
APR Statistical data ....
Poll Statistics .........
Polls created           : 0
Polls destroyed         : 0
Polls cleared           : 0
Network Statistics ......
Sockets created         : 0
Sockets accepted        : 0
Sockets closed          : 0
Sockets cleared         : 0
Total send calls        : 0
Minimum send length     : 10000000
Maximum send length     : 0
Average send length     : -nan
Total recv calls        : 0
Minimum recv length     : 10000000
Maximum recv length     : 0
Average recv length     : -nan
Receive timeouts        : 0
Receive errors          : 0
Receive resets          : 0
Last receive error      : 0
Total sendfile calls    : 0
Minimum sendfile length : 10000000
Maximum sendfile length : 0
SSL Network Statistics ..
Sockets created         : 0
Sockets accepted        : 0
Sockets closed          : 0
Sockets cleared         : 0
APR Terminated
Sep 23, 2014 2:11:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
SEVERE: An incompatible version 1.1.29 of the APR based Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version 1.1.30
APR Statistical data ....
Poll Statistics .........
Polls created           : 0
Polls destroyed         : 0
Polls cleared           : 0
Network Statistics ......
Sockets created         : 0
Sockets accepted        : 0
Sockets closed          : 0
Sockets cleared         : 0
Total send calls        : 0
Minimum send length     : 10000000
Maximum send length     : 0
Average send length     : -nan
Total recv calls        : 0
Minimum recv length     : 10000000
Maximum recv length     : 0
Average recv length     : -nan
Receive timeouts        : 0
Receive errors          : 0
Receive resets          : 0
Last receive error      : 0
Total sendfile calls    : 0
Minimum sendfile length : 10000000
Maximum sendfile length : 0
SSL Network Statistics ..
Sockets created         : 0
Sockets accepted        : 0
Sockets closed          : 0
Sockets cleared         : 0
APR Terminated
Sep 23, 2014 2:11:58 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 23, 2014 2:11:58 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-42919"]
Sep 23, 2014 2:11:58 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 983 ms
Sep 23, 2014 2:11:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 23, 2014 2:11:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.55
Sep 23, 2014 2:11:58 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 23, 2014 2:11:58 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-42919"]
Sep 23, 2014 2:11:58 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 64 ms
Connected to server
[2014-09-23 02:11:59,386] Artifact perc-web:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000f6480000, 88604672, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 88604672 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/ivan/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/bin/hs_err_pid18653.log
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:60749', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from server
[2014-09-23 02:12:04,177] Artifact perc-web:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
```

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu! Could you please add the error message you get when running `sudo apt-get upgrade libtcnative-1` to your question?

Comment: that strange, but everything works now even with this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomcat 7.0.55 requires libtcnative-1 1.1.30, but there's no such package available from the standard repositories.

I've backported libtcnative 1.1.31 for Ubuntu 14.04, available from https://launchpad.net/~pharmgkb/+archive/ubuntu/trusty.

You can upgrade to it with:

```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pharmgkb/trusty
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get upgrade libtcnative-1
```